# stat(FILENAME) in awk

Tags: awk

How can I get file attribute with awk ?

or

Is there an equivalent to c/php `stat()` function ?

- obviously when awk'ing a pipe, file attribute would be undefined.
- I know I can use perl, but this would rewrite my awk's script.
- this in on ubuntu, any alternative to awk is OK (gawk for instance).

my awk is already gawk

```
awk --version
GNU Awk 4.0.1
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2012 Free Software Foundation.
```

adding `@load "filefuncs" ;` (be it in `BEGIN { }` clause or before it.)

result in

```
gawk: stat-to-php.awk:4:     @load "filefuncs" ;
gawk: stat-to-php.awk:4:      ^ syntax error
```

Comment: You may want to write extension for `gawk` https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Internal-File-Description.html#Internal-File-Description

Comment: well, thanks for the hint, this looks slightly less hellish than writing PHP extension ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21816818/how-to-use-stat-command-inside-awk

Comment: @cuonglm - there's no need to write it, it already exists for GNU `awk`.  enable with `@load "filefuncs"` at the start of the awk script.  Installed as `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gawk/filefuncs.so` on my debian sid system (`gawk` package version 1:4.1.3+dfsg-0.1)

Comment: @cas: Ah right, it's `/usr/lib/gawk/filefuncs.so` in my Manjaro.

Comment: That's odd.  According to https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Feature-History.html#Feature-History, dynamic extensions were added to gawk in version 3.1.  Maybe try `awk -l filefuncs` instead....or put the @load **before** the `BEGIN {}`, not inside it.

Comment: my testing indicates that @load doesn't work inside BEGIN or END or any statement block, has to be outside it.

Comment: proof that it works: `awk  '@load "filefuncs"; {stat(ARGV[1],f) ; print f["mtime"]; exit} ' test.file 
1465381265`.  Maybe your gawk is compiled with it disabled.

Comment: +1. (dunno why this Q was downvoted, it's an interesting question).

Comment: @cas The [feature history](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Feature-History.html) states that the dynamic extension feature was “completely redone” in 4.1, and `@load` doesn't exist on gawk 4.0.1 on Debian wheezy. `@load` must have been introduced in 4.1. Wheezy doesn't have `/usr/lib/gawk` either, you'd have to build the extension yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your system has a `stat` command, you can let `awk` call that command and read its output via `getline`.

edit:

```
awk '{ "stat -c%y " $1 | getline ts ;}'
```

will put in `ts` value of `stat -c%y $1`